# Lock no mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Bom galera, estou usando o mongodb para desenvolver projetos na faculdade, gostaria de saber (documentação é fraca no site do mongo https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/ ) como funciona o lock nele, com detalhamento, se ele da lock no banco inteiro, na coleção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele dá um "lock" apenas no documento de uma coleção que estiver sendo gravado ou editado.
Quando há muitas operações de leitura/escrita, esta operação acontece em memória, e o "read" pode ser feito antes mesmo da gravação real no banco de dados.
Se falhar o mongod, os dados não persistem.
O mongo possui commit intervals, que gravam os dados da "ram" para o "disco" de tempos em tempos.